# How to delete all the duplicates keeping only one of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I want to delete all the duplicates keeping only one of them.

My query should delete all the duplicated data :

```
WITH todelete As (
      select em.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
                                order by (select null)) as cnt
      from empmission em
)

DELETE FROM todelete
WHERE cnt > 2;
```

Comment: Actually, it should leave two duplicates. Your where clause should be `WHERE cnt > 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Of all I suggest you  not to use CTE use temp table for your solution
 use the below link for finding why I ma saying this

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table

to know more use the below link

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/X517150913-Difference-between-CTE-and-Temp-Table-and-Table-Variable.html

Now lets us get back to your solution, i have used Temp Table

```
Select e.emp_num,e.from_date,e.to_date,e.[ req_ser],e.[ req_year],COUNT(1) number_of_duplicates
into #temp1 from empmission  e
group by emp_num,from_date,to_date,[ req_ser],[ req_year]

Truncate Table empmission 


 Insert into empmission 
 Select t.emp_num,
       t.from_date, 
       t.to_date,
       t.[ req_ser],
       t.[ req_year]
     from #temp1 t
   Drop Table #temp1      --Droping the temp table

  Select * from empmission
```

Or You can go with CTE
As

```
WITH todelete As (
  select em.*,
         row_number() over (partition by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
                            order by (select null)) as cnt
  from empmission em
  )
  DELETE FROM todelete
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Zohar in comments,your query will keep *`two`* duplicate rows not *`one`*..To keep only one row change your query like below..

[Check out this question and all its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) for several ways to delete like rownumber,group by ,self join and also optimization tips on when to use group by vs rownumber..

```
WITH todelete As (
      select em.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_num, [from_date],[to_date],[ req_ser], [ req_year]
                                order by (select null)) as cnt
      from empmission em
)

DELETE FROM todelete
WHERE cnt > 1;
```